# How to pass cookies while redirecting to external url in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cookies, angular11

On click of a button, i need to open a link(for example say https://angular.io/) in new tab and pass cookie with the url. i can open the link in new tab but how to pass the cookies.

```
var cookie = "hello-world"
onSubmit() {
   window. open(
       "https://angular.io", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: One site cannot create cookies for another site

Comment: so, on submit if i am running on site localhost:4200, i cannot pass or set cookie to https://34.12.34.123.png from localhost:4200?

Comment: A site can only create a cookie for its own domain, or a domain at a higher level.  Such as `my.site.com` can make a cookie for `my.site.com` or `.site.com`.

Comment: ok. so if we have to pass cookie within the same domain, how will we achieve it?

Comment: You don't pass cookies, you set cookies.  And then when the requests are made, the browser will include the cookies associated with the domain with the request for you.